# iPad: Captured video w/ AVCam Sample, but it is 1080x720, how do you compress it?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, avcam

Captured video with AVCam Sample Project, but it is huge at 1080x720 resolution.  How can I compress for saving to a web server?

I modified the sample code to not save the video file to the AssetsLibrary in "AvCamCaptureManager.m" "recordingDidFinishToOutputFileURL", so I take that outputfile url and send it to my webserver using ASIHttp.  These video files are huge, I want to reduce their resolution to 568x320 to reduce the file size.

Given the uncompressed url, how do I compress it to a smaller file format and/or resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just saw your question, if it's still of any help, try reducing the quelity for the whole session

```
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
```

or

```
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow;
```

The first will give smaller files while keeping a decent quality, and the latter will give a very small file with the lowest quality available for your device.